# How to install an older version of Chrome that HP UFT currently supports?

Tags: qtp, chrome

As HP UFT only support older versions of non-IE browsers, how can I install the older versions of Chrome? It seems obvious to others maybe, but I don't get it. I have 2 problems here and I will really appreciate if someone can point me to a solution.
1. There is nowhere to download an older version of Chrome anymore
2. After I install an older version Chrome, it will automatically get updated to current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I've used Google Chromium blog in the past, it is a repository of all the older builds.

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html

2. Change your settings to manual update to newer versions, this will prevent automatic updates.

Comment: The link helps, thank you! The manual update however took me a while googling. Have to do it in chrome://plugins/